# "DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated...." when executing rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I follow the [Spree Guides](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html), I got an error message ,

```
yulong@ubuntu:~/mystore$ rake db:create
rake db:create
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    rake aborted!
    Fixtures is not a class
yulong@ubuntu:~/mystore$ rails g spree:site
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at /home/yulong/mystore/config/application.rb:7)
    [DEPRECATION WARNING] Nested I18n namespace lookup under "activerecord.attributes.checkout" is no longer supported
   create  lib/spree_site.rb
   remove  public/index.html
   append  public/robots.txt
   append  db/seeds.rb
```

Comment: Which versions of Rails and Spree are you using?

Comment: @rdvdijk rails 3.1.0,and spree "0.60.1"

Comment: My guess is that Spree isn't Rails 3.1 compatible yet. (Also see [this post](http://spreecommerce.com/blog/2011/06/16/rails-3-1/).) Can you try with the latest Rails 3.0 version?

Answer (score 4):

Please go through following link, which will help you to  fix this issue in rails 3.1

http://martinciu.com/2011/07/difference-between-class_inheritable_attribute-and-class_attribute.html